# Всегда нужно "удалять" изобажения функцией imagedestroy()?

Tags: php, файлы, изображения, ресурсы

Всегд нужно удалять ресурсы изображений ф-ей imagedestroy() или они автоматически убиваются после окончания работы скрипта?

Думаю что они самоликвидируются после заверш скрипта. Почему спрашиваю: Ну если есть такая функция, значит она не просто так придумана. Может быть (а может и не быть?) так, что не удаляющиеся ресурсы, дескрипторы могут накапливаться и через некоторое время система станет не работоспособной.

---

Всегда нужно "убирать за собой"?

Comment: Если за время работы скрипта у ва обрабатывается только одно изображение. Тогда вам не стоит заморочиться с удалением. В случае если вы обрабатываете в пакетном режиме и неизвестно сколько их в пакете будет тогда да это имеет смысл. Но вообще правила хорошего тона говорят что если ты нагадил то будь добр убери за собой.

Comment: @fens Мне кажется, комментарий тянет на ответ.

Comment: Обрабатывается максимум 10 файлов. Да. буду удалять.